# Joomla 1.5 is not updating template changes

Tags: joomla

I've got a component that I'm editing on the fly while developing.  All of a sudden, things are taking a while to show changes when I apply them.

Everything from template settings to raw code that I upload via FTP.

Changes are taking around 5 minutes to show up when I apply them.  It happens across separate browsers, so I can rule out cache issues.

Comment: If on localhost it updates immediately, the problem is with server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with Joomla install.  Re-Installed Joomla and everything is working fine.  I have no idea what went wrong.